# Center a div with a max-width without margin: auto;

Tags: html, css

Thats my pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/oxgqpJ

I want to center a div with a fixed max width, but when I am under the fixed max width I want a margin of 10% on each side , because at the moment there is no visible margin in that resolution area.

The drawback is using that 10% margin on each side the div is not centered anymore it starts on the left side...

How can I fix that?

```
<div id="container">
  Center me with a fixed max width, but when I am under the fixed max width I want a margin of 10% on each side , because at the moment there is no visible margin.
</div>



#container
{
  margin: 0 auto;

  // use instead in smaller resolutions
  //margin: 0 10%;
  max-width:1024px;
  background:orange;
}
```

Comment: You want horizontally Or vertically center. What is your expected output?

Comment: horizontally centered therefore margin: 0 auto;

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGBmNz this?

Comment: just remove this " // use instead in smaller resolutions" and "margin: 0 auto;" and of corse this "//" from your exemple  CSS Comments is this : /* xxx */    .... http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_syntax2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I fully understand your question, but maybe this will do.
I would just use the margin to make sure it's centered and then padding to ensure the 10% on either side.
Obviously this means that it only satisfies your requirements for the actual content of the div (the text) rather than the div itself, but again; maybe that's good enough?

```
#container
{
  max-width:1024px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  background:orange;
}
```

Comment: You are the one with the best working solution. I just put a div around my real life centered div (not codepen fake sample) give it a padding è voila! Thanks!

Comment: No problem - glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this, for example:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    #container { margin: 0 10%; }
}
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to depend on Media Query to apply different margin for same object on various condition . In addition to the class you have created , apply this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
/* For mobile phones: */
  #container {
     margin:0 10%;
  }
}
```

In other higher screen the other css property will be applied ! 
Learn how to use Media query : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp